# Matlab отрисовка графика

Tags: matlab

знатоки.
Рисую функцию, но не пойму что хочет от меня Matlab.
Ругается, но всё равно выводит её.
Может кто подсказать что я делаю не так?
В Matlab я полный профан...

```
clc; %очищает весь текст командного окна
clear;% очищает рабочую область

%первый график
f1 = @(x)x.^4-x.^3-2*x.^2+3*x-3;
subplot (2,1,1); %позволяет печатать график в различных частях графического окна
fplot(f1,[-5 5],'r');% производит построение графиков функции одной переменной
hold on;%включает режим сохранения текущего графика и свойств объекта axes
title('$x^4-x^3-2*x^2+3*x-3$','fontsize',14,'interpreter','latex');%размещает текст над графиком
xlabel('$X$','fontsize',14,'interpreter','latex');% подписывает оси
ylabel('$Y$','fontsize',14,'interpreter','latex');% подписывает оси
grid on;%наносит координатную сетку на текущие оси

%второй график
subplot (2,1,2);
f2 = @(x,y)sin(x+y) - 1.5*x*y;
f3 = @(x,y)x.^2+y.^2-1;
%fimplicit(@(x,y)sin(x+y) - (1.5*x*y),'g'); %строит график заданный неявной функцией
p1 = fimplicit (f2,[-5 5],'m');
hold on;
p2 = fimplicit(f3, [-5 5],'g');
hold on;
title('$sin(x+y)-1.5*x*y, x^2+y^2=1$','fontsize',14,'interpreter','latex');
xlabel('$X$','fontsize',14,'interpreter','latex');
ylabel('$Y$','fontsize',14,'interpreter','latex');
text(3.352,2.1,'$(3.356,1.207)$','fontsize',14,'interpreter','latex','color','k');
plot(3.356,1.207,'ko');%выводит окружность в заданные координаты
grid on;
```

```
Warning: Function behaves unexpectedly on array inputs. To improve
performance, properly vectorize your function to return an output with
the same size and shape as the input arguments. 
> In matlab.graphics.function.ImplicitFunctionLine>getFunction
  In matlab.graphics.function/ImplicitFunctionLine/updateFunction
  In matlab.graphics.function.ImplicitFunctionLine.set.Function_I
  In matlab.graphics.function.ImplicitFunctionLine.set.Function
  In matlab.graphics.function.ImplicitFunctionLine
  In fimplicit>singleFimplicit (line 193)
  In fimplicit>@(f)singleFimplicit(cax,f,limits,extraOpts,args) (line 152)
  In fimplicit>vectorizeFimplicit (line 152)
  In fimplicit (line 126)
  In labr1_2 (line 19)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте для начала исправить

```
f2 = @(x,y)sin(x+y) - 1.5*x.*y;
```

Здесь такая же логика, как и с возведением в степень - поэлементное умножение матриц производится оператором .*

Comment: Да, спасибо. Уже пришёл к этому на прошлой неделе.